# How to send image from Express to React

Tags: reactjs, image, express, fetch, blob

I have my images stored in the Express backend with Multer, now i want the client (React) to pull them with fetch request, any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Please add the minimal working code, it would help us to assist you.

Comment: i just need the theory behind the process of sending an image from express to react & rendering it ... all may images are stored in express backend